# Is there a grammatical rule for using "read" between parentheses?

Tags: parentheses

As an example:

> I am bored (read: lazy).

I wish to know if English Grammar has a formal construct for this usage.

Comment: This placement of a word is *in parentheses*. If you write **(A) B (C)**, B is *between parentheses*.

Answer (score 26):

Looking for occurrences of `(read` in the [*Corpus of Contemporary American English*](http://www.americancorpus.org/), I find among the 33 first hits:

- 18 are of the form: “***she promised her supporters (read: voters)***”
- 5 are of the form: “***she promised her supporters (read voters)***”
- 10 are unrelated to your question, like “***(read more in…)***”

These shows two things: there are two alternatives, and while the use of a colon after *reading* is preferred, it is not a hard and fast rule. Also, when the colon is omitted, italicisation may be used for clarification of the intent, as in: “she promised her supporters (read *voters*)”; unfortunately, this is not reflected in the statistics given above.

Personally, I prefer using the colon, as I find it more readable.

Comment: Don't you mean "more read:able"? ;-)

Comment: As an alternative, you could italicise or use quotation marks. But the colon is indeed attractive.

Answer (score 7):

I agree that this expression has a more "informal and chatty" nature; I would choose it over "i.e.," for example, as a conspiratorial aside to the reader, e.g. poking fun at doublespeak: "enhanced interrogation(read: torture)", implying "we all know what they *really* mean when they say that!" It's also handy to know that italicization may be used in this intent-clarifying context rather than a colon.

Also, it seems that it's possible to have your cake and eat it too; i.e., retain the sardonic connotation of the aside while achieving a "more polished effect": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilicet — "...scilicet, abbreviated as sc. ...is Latin for 'it is permitted to know'. Sc. provides a parenthetic clarification, removes an ambiguity, or supplies a word omitted in preceding text..."

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the use of "read" here is fairly informal and chatty. For a more polished effect, prefer "id est" or "i.e.," viz:

> I am bored, i.e., lazy.

Comment: Which form of "read" is this? the imperative (rhymes with "reed"), or the form that rhymes with "red"?

Comment: @sshanky "reed" [/ɹid/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_pronunciation), as in "you should *read* the preceding text as: <whatever>"

Comment: I'd say it is the form that rhymes with "red". (read: I disagree)

I think of "read: X" as "red as X". Seems intuitive to me.