# What is the pronunciation of parenthesized ‘read’?

Tags: pronunciation

In sentences like the following one, what is the pronunciation of the word *read*? I have always pronounced it *red*, as past-tense, but I have, a couple of times, heard it pronounced *reed*, as instruction to the reader.

> The text was unhelpful (read a waste of money) for the class.

(As a side note/question, is there a specific term for that usage of read or its parenthesized sub-sentence?)

Comment: I think your side note was asked recently: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14059/is-there-a-grammatical-rule-for-using-read-between-parentheses  Maybe not; the question wasn't amazingly clear and the answers go in a different direction.  I'm not aware of any name for the convention, in any event.  I sort of suspect a certain stripe of person may refer to it as "a videlicet", but that's kind of cheese, since videlicet/viz. is just the word used to do the same thing by way of Latin.

Comment: Related to [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/what-words-are-commonly-mispronounced-by-literate-people-who-read-them-before-the/1438#1438), but I think it deserves its own topic.

Answer (score 10):

I've always said it *reed*, understanding it in the instruction-to-the-reader sense.  I can't have heard somebody say it out loud more than a handful of times in my life, but in none of the cases did the speaker say *red*.

Comment: +1, that's my interpretation, and how I've heard it too, as if it's short for "read that as..."

Comment: It would *read* better if it was punctuated like so (I think): `read: a waste of money`.

Comment: @Benjol, actually the colon works for the opposite as well.

Answer (score 7):

The two forms of the word are spelled the same in English, but the same construction exists in Swedish, and as the spelling differs it's clearly in the form of an instruction to read:

> Texten var värdelös (läs pengaslöseri) för klassen.

Read [rid] translates to *läs* while read [rɛd] translates to *läste*.

Comment: Also, "lees" in Dutch, "lies" or "sprich" in German, "читай" in Russian. All imperative.

Comment: That’s one of the explanations given in one of the MetaFilter threads, but a compelling argument for the other way is also given there. `:-|`

Comment: Note: the Swedish equivalent to the /red/ pronunciation is not _läste_ (past tense), but _läst_ (past participle). A simple past tense would make no sense in either language.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't heard it spoken much either, but I have heard both.  Both make sense to me.  The "red" pronunciation could be just as much an instruction to the reader as "reed", simply expressed differently.  (Imagine demonstrating something, and saying "it's done like so", or saying "do it like so".)

Answer (score 3):

It is pronounced /rid/ ("reed").

Here is what the OED has to say about this question:

> **9. a.** To adopt, give, or exhibit as a reading in a particular passage.
>   Hence, to substitute or understand *for*
>   (what is said or written).
>
> **1659** HAMMOND *Acts xv.* Annot., The Æthiopick
>   and other interpreters retain.., *what
>   you would not have done to your
>   selves, do not ye to another,*.. for
>   which other Jewish writers read, *doing
>   as they would be done to.* **1697** BENTLEY
>   *Phal.* 20, I cannot..comprehend why the
>   most learned Is. Casaubon will read
>   σπεύδοντα in this passage, and not
>   σπένδοντα. **1759** RUDDIMAN *Animadver.
>   Vind. Buchanan* 60 Instead of..
>   *sexagesimo quinto*, we should read,..
>   *sexagesimo nono*. **1847** MADDEN *Layamon's
>   Brut.* III. 346 For *Lovaine* some copies
>   of Wace read *Alemaigne*. **1868** M. E. G.
>   DUFF *Pol. Survey* 16 For monasteries,
>   we should read convents,
>   mission-houses, and seminaries. **1966**
>   ‘A. HALL’ *9th Directive* xxi. 193 For
>   snatch read abduction. For swop read
>   exchange. Never a bloody spade. **1967**
>   *Listener* 4 May 593/2 Links between the
>   cultures of ‘Indonesia’ (read
>   southeast Asia) and west and central
>   Africa.

This OED quote was featured in a [Metafilter thread](http://ask.metafilter.com/92739/How-do-you-pronounce-read) on this very question, and there is a [nearly identical Metafilter thread](http://ask.metafilter.com/162666/Is-the-parenthetical-read-pronounced-reed-or-red) two years later.  Both feature lots of opinions and argumentation, but the OED argument (among others) makes the answer fairly clear.

Comment: The OED article doesn’t provide any kind of answer or argument to this question at all. They define the meaning of the verb in this sense. The verb can be used in all forms in this sense, just like any other verb. The OED article is equally compatible with interpreting the single word _read_ in this particular usage as “/riːd/ this as X” and “to be /red/ as X”.